# What will a boot look like in the systemd journal (journalctl)?

Tags: systemd, startup, systemd-journald, journalctl

What should I look for in the systemd journal to find when the latest boot happened?

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username) for more `journalctl` hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an empty `-b,--boot` option to `journalctl` in order to request "the current boot", then `-n 0` to request zero lines of output, which leaves just the header:

```
journalctl -b -n 0
```

Example output:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-02-10 17:46:08 PST, end at Thu 2021-02-11 15:36:01 PST. --
```

Or if the `-n 0` fails to output the proper information try the number 1.

```
~# journalctl -b -n 0
-- No entries --
~# journalctl -b -n 1
-- Logs begin at Mon 2021-02-08 20:24:14 AST, end at Thu 2021-02-11 21:33:56 AST. --
Feb 11 21:33:56 zeus-H370M systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
```